# vector of list memory leak in C++ on OSX 10.8

Tags: c++, list, memory, vector, stl

I'm having memory problems with in implementing a vector< list< size_t> >. Here's the code:

```
struct structure{
    vector< list<size_t>  > Ar;

    structure(int n){
        Ar.reserve(n);
        for(size_t i =0; (int) i<  n;i++){
            list<size_t> L;
            Ar.push_back(L);
        }
    }

    ~structure(){
       vector<list<size_t> >::iterator it = Ar.begin();
       while(it < Ar.end()){
           (*it).clear();
           ++it;
       }
       Ar.clear();
    }


};

int main() {

    for(size_t k = 0; k <100 ; k++){    
        structure test_s = structure(1000*(100 - k));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The physical memory allocation to this program should be going down as time progresses, because less and less memory is being allocated to test_s, through the use of 100 - k in the constructor. This isn't what I'm observing! Rather, the physical memory increases around half way through the run!

Since I am using this code in a bigger program that eats up a huge amount of memory, this is a bit of a catastrophe!

There are two details that I find strange:

Firstly, there is no progressive increment in the physical memory usage, even though the size of the object changes at every stage of the for loop, rather the memory increases suddenly at around the 50th iteration of the for loop. This happens consistently each run I do (and I've done many!). The iteration at which the memory increases is not random!

Secondly, when I pass a static size_t (e.g. 10000) to the structure(size_t) constructor, I don't get the problem anymore. As you can probably guess, a static value isn't very useful for my code, as I need to be able to dynamically allocate the size of the structure object.

I am compiling with g++ on macos 10.8.3. I haven't tried compiling on another platform, as I would prefer to keep working on my Mac.

All of the memory management tools I have tried (Apple Instruments and Valgrind) haven't been particularly helpful. Valgrind only returns references to libraries and not to the program itself.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Cheers,
Plamen

Comment: Your destructor does nothing and your constructor can be written `structure(int n) : Ar(n) {}`. There's no memory leak here.

Comment: Rule of zero. Your class doesn't need a destructor. I am not even bothering to check if it is the cause.

Comment: How did you find out that your program has a memory leak? You are aware that your program does not have to return memory to the operating system (immediately)?

Comment: I observed the memory increasing in Activity Monitor. Is this wrong? Thanks for the tips on the constructor and destructor. I'm pretty sure these are not the cause; if I pass a literal to the constructor, I don't get the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any leak in that code, but a lot of unneeded code. The simplified code would be:

```
struct structure{
    vector< list<size_t>  > Ar;

    structure(int n): Ar(n) // initialize the vector with n empty lists
    {
    }

    // destructor unneeded, since Ar will be destroyed anyway, with all of its elements.
};
```

But this doesn't answer your question.

Heap memory allocation doesn't means physical memory allocation. Modern OS use virtual memory, usually backed by paging file. Heap allocation get memory from virtual memory and OS decide if more or less physical memory is needed. Freeing memory to the virtual memory doesn't means free that physical memory (if is not needed for other process, why to do that in that time?).

Also, heap memory allocation are not directly translated to virtual memory allocations. Usually, virtual memory allocation have a big granularity so is not suitable for small allocations. Then, the heap manager allocate blocks of virtual memory and manage that for all heap allocations. (If virtual memory is not enough, heap manager will ask for more). When not used blocks of virtual memory are freed depends on how is heap manager implemented.

To do the things a bit more complex, allocating and deallocating different size of memory would produce heap fragmentation, depending on allocation/deallocation pattern and how is the heap implemented.

Physical memory is not a good indicator of memory leak in this type of program. Would be better private (virtual) memory or similar one.

Comment: Thanks! I will change the memory values I'm looking at. Is there a way to help the allocator with fragmented memory whilst the program is running? I will also get rid of the wasteful code!

Comment: I have changed the code to avoid allocation in time. Now, I create one structure object that allocates sufficient memory for the vector for the whole for loop. Instead of using the destructor to clear the memory, I added a function to clear the content of the lists in the vector. This is sufficient for the memory management for my program, as the contents of the lists are much much larger than the container itself, and there is no jump in the memory allocation anymore! Thanks everyone for their contributions!

Answer (score 2):

The C++ allocator doesn't necessarily return memory to the OS when it's done with it, but usually keeps it around since you're probably going to need it soon.

I'm not familiar with the details of the OS X allocator, but it's quite common for an allocator to grab memory from the OS in larger chunks and then treat them as separate pools.
This may be what you're seeing, with sudden growth as the first chunk of memory is filled.
It's also possible that you're passing some threshold between "larger" allocations and "smaller" allocations, and you're just seeing an added pool for slightly smaller things - some allocators do that.
It's also possible that the cause is something entirely different, of course.

The difference when you're using the same size for each one is most likely because it's easy for the allocator to fill the request using a block of the same size that was recently freed.

When the blocks have different sizes it's faster to allocate a new block with a different size than to divide a free block into two smaller ones.
(This can also unfortunately lead to memory fragmentation. If you get many scattered small blocks, it may happen that a large allocation request can't be fulfilled despite there being enough room in total.)

In summary: Memory allocators and operating systems are quite complicated these days, and you can't look at growth in memory allocation and say for certain that you have a memory leak.
I would trust valgrind and Instruments in your case.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to minimize the use of different sizes for the allocation. It seems to me that lists should present this memory uncertainty in general: since objects can be added and removed to a list dynamically, won't the allocator be confused in general about how much memory is in use? Sorry, I am a newb in this website: should I open a new thread to ask this?